# How to move unique Ids from Kafka to elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

How to move unique Ids from Kafka to elastic search ?

I have done using Elasticsearch connector from kafka to Elasticsearch But it is sending the entire Data. I need to send only the Unique Ids from kafka to ES

Comment: Do you mean that you only want to import the message keys and not the data? Maybe you should show some code of what you're doing

Comment: yes i want to send keys but not data. I didn't find any suitable link to start @Val

Comment: Please check the second part of my above comment

Comment: I dont hace any code I am new to this I need any links to know

Comment: If you are using the connector from Confluent, you can't currently only write the keys I believe. You can configure it to only write the values http://docs.confluent.io/3.1.1/connect/connect-elasticsearch/docs/configuration_options.html If you need that feature, I encourage you to open an issue on the github here https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch